# Java JSpinner does not show anything

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

Right at the start I would like to mention that yes, there already is a question from another user asking basically the same. However that thread does not really have an answer which solves the problem and since the thread is already about seven years old, I suspect I might not get an answer if I would ask in that one.

So the Problem is, that a JSpinner does not show anything unless the Frame on which it is displayed is resized. I have looked at the oracle page "how to use JSpinners", I have looked at a seperate tutorial site and I have tried the solutions people in the other thread have mentioned. None of them have worked for me. So here is the code, help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package pack;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class Test extends JFrame{
        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    JSpinner spinner;
    
    public Test() {
        
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setContentPane(new JLabel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
        SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 2, 1);
        spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.setVisible(true);
        spinner.setSize(100,100);
        
        add(spinner);
        
        repaint();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {new Test();}
}
```

Comment: As with just about all questions which have similar issues, move `setVisible` to the end of the `Test` method.  Swing is lazy, so it won't automatically update/re-layout a UI when you change it.  You're required to let it know.  So, if you "can't" move `setVisible` to the end of the method, you're required to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container which was changed

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I´ll remember that if I encounter something similar in the future.